# Gridview count rows = 2 but no record on webpage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a bit of code thats not working and can not find out wy and dont get any error. I am trying to fill a gridview with a datatable from a viewstate. When I count the rows of the gridview it says it has 2 rows but on the webpage I can`t even see 1.

the code:

```
   Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("myData"), DataTable)
   GridViewArtikelenSelected.DataSource = dt
   GridViewArtikelenSelected.DataBind()
   Dim test As Integer = GridViewArtikelenSelected.Rows.Count
```

Comment: what is the code for your `GridView` control?

Comment: Have you added some rows in the grid to work as header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be your GridView is in `UpdatePanel`, which might be not  refreshing after Binding of grid.

Comment: the code for my gridview control shud be oke becase i do get records in it when i go on the page and fill the viewstate with record by an id from request querystring but when i saved the page to database and then load the page again the records dont show up, when i use the same way and the count realy is 2. And there is an Panel around it but no updatepanel

Comment: Tanx m8 the panel whas the problem.